# How install CronJobs for viefaucet script

Tags: cron

[I am trying to add at tabels from picture 1 CronJobs for reload every mounth at 1st day. How can i do ? Need only the link(path) not code .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqoyr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could've known the right way to do it when you would've read the Documentation you got with the Script.

**Cronjob is used to update currency price, contest and lottery status, ... automatically.
From Cpanel, click on Cron Jobs, add the following cronjobs:**

**Cpanel**
curl FAUCETURL/cronjob/fiveminutes
Every 5 minutes

curl FAUCETURL/cronjob/daily
Every day at 0:00

**Hostinger, AAPanel, ...**
wget -O /dev/null FAUCETURL/cronjob/fiveminutes
Every 5 minutes

wget -O /dev/null FAUCETURL/cronjob/daily
Every day at 0:00

The Link for these two Cron Jobs would be:
FAUCETURL/cronjob/fiveminutes
FAUCETURL/cronjob/daily